# intercambio de elementos LU en una matriz en Python

Tags: python, matrices

Tengo la siguiente matriz

> ```
>  -0.4683    0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -2.8891   -4.8416   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -3.8950  -10.0595  -8.6966   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -6.8937  -14.9937 -16.4472  -9.6883   0.0000 
> -15.3525  -28.1960 -26.4046 -16.5958  -6.2796
> ```

quiero obtener esta salida

> ```
>  -0.4683  -4.8416  -8.6966  -9.6883  -6.2796 
>  -2.8891 -10.0595 -16.4472 -16.5958   0.0000 
>  -3.8950 -14.9937 -26.4046   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -6.8937 -28.1960   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
> -15.3525   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
> ```

mi codigo es.

```
for i in range(len(prueba)):
  for j in range(len(prueba[0])):
    matrizA[j][i] = prueba[len(prueba)-j-1][i]
```

sin embargo obtengo la siguiente salida:

> ```
>  15.3525 -28.1960 -26.4046 -16.5958  -6.2796 
>  -6.8937 -14.9937 -16.4472  -9.6883   0.0000 
>  -3.8950 -10.0595  -8.6966   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -2.8891  -4.8416   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000 
>  -0.4683   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
> ```

Comment: Hola Angel, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Es una lista (list) de listas o un array de numpy?

Comment: Es una lista, por cierto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

## Operación in-place

Si queremos hacerlo in-place hay que tener en cuenta dos cosas:

- El ciclo que itera las columnas solo debe iterar hasta la diagonal principal.
- En cada iteración **hay que hacer un intercambio de dos items**, no una simple reasignación. Si solo reasignamos perdemos un item.

El código puede quedar algo así:

```
matriz_a =  [[ -0.4683,   0.0000,   0.0000,   0.0000,  0.0000], 
             [ -2.8891,  -4.8416,   0.0000,   0.0000,  0.0000],
             [ -3.8950, -10.0595,  -8.6966,   0.0000,  0.0000],
             [ -6.8937, -14.9937, -16.4472,  -9.6883,  0.0000],
             [-15.3525, -28.1960, -26.4046, -16.5958, -6.2796]]


n_fils = len(matriz_a)
n_cols = len(matriz_a[0])

for i in range(n_fils):
    for j in range(1, n_cols - i):
        matriz_a[i][j], matriz_a[i + j][j] = matriz_a[i + j][j], matriz_a[i][j]
```

> ```
> >>> matriz_a
>
> [[ -0.4683,  -4.8416,  -8.6966,  -9.6883, -6.2796],
>  [ -2.8891, -10.0595, -16.4472, -16.5958,     0.0],
>  [  -3.895, -14.9937, -26.4046,      0.0,     0.0],
>  [ -6.8937,  -28.196,      0.0,      0.0,     0.0],
>  [-15.3525,      0.0,      0.0,      0.0,     0.0]]
> ```

## Generando nueva matriz

El algoritmo que podemos usar es exactamente el mismo, pero solo que en éste caso si debemos iterar sobre toda la columna dado que no hay intercambio y además debemos usar el módulo para indizar de forma adecuada:

```
n_fils = len(matriz_a)
n_cols = len(matriz_a[0])

nueva_matriz = [
    [matriz_a[(i + j) % n_cols][j] for j in range(n_cols)] for i in range(n_fils)
    ]
```

> ```
> >>> nueva_matriz
>
> [[ -0.4683,  -4.8416,  -8.6966,  -9.6883, -6.2796],
>  [ -2.8891, -10.0595, -16.4472, -16.5958,     0.0],
>  [  -3.895, -14.9937, -26.4046,      0.0,     0.0],
>  [ -6.8937,  -28.196,      0.0,      0.0,     0.0],
>  [-15.3525,      0.0,      0.0,      0.0,     0.0]]
> ```